# My Javascript is returning with Internal error

Tags: javascript, date

Hello I compiled a Javascript into a notepad file and opened a pdf. After this I tried to print with footer function and it said internal error occurred.
 Here's the script:
    app.addMenuItem({
        cName: "Print with Footer",
        cParent: "File",
        nPos: 20,
        cExec: "PrtFooter();"
    });

```
//Print bookmarked Pages function PrtFooter() {

for (var p = 0; p < this.numPages; p++)

{

    var fd = this.addField("Date", "text", p, [10, 10, 300, 28]);
    fd.textSize = 8;
    fd.value = "Date: " + util.printd("yyyy/mmm/dd", new Date()) + " (" + this.path + ")"

    var fp = this.addField(String("page" + p + 1), "text", p, [330, 10, 280, 28]);

    fp.textSize = 8;
    fp.value = "Page: " + String(p + 1) + "/" + this.numPages;

}

app.execMenuItem("Print");

var OK = app.alert("Delete Date / Filename?", 2, 2);

if (OK == 4) {

    var x = removeField("Date");

    for (var p = 0; p < this.numPages; p++)

    {

        var x = removeField(String("page" + p + 1));

    }
}

}
```

Comment: Wait. You compiled JavaScript into Notepad and opened a PDF? That doesn't make sense. Also, your question doesn't contain enough code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Zeta - Then he tried to print it with the footer function, makes perfect sense ?